# scaffold, belongs_to :user doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffold

I just generated a scaffold. I added has_many :posts to the user.rb and added belongs_to :user to the post.rb. But now when i try to create a new post it tells me that an error occurred and that *user must exist?
Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: please post relevant code..

Comment: you need to add the user to the post you're creating or allow to pass a nil user to the association